# Python recursive function to calculate the sum of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if (n<=0):
        return 0
    elif(n==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)+1
    
n=int(input())
print(fibonacci(n))
```

can any one explain what is the logic adding 1 at the  end of this return statement fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)+1

Comment: There is none. Its simply wrong. At best it is a modified version of the Fibonacci series, but not the Fibonacci series itself.

Comment: @Flow The code works correctly (it returns the **sum** of the Fibonacci numbers) but I don't know why yet. This is more a mathematical question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Interesting observation! With this I would suggest to rename the function.

Comment: @Flow Right, the name is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

The function is "correct" (but see below), because it is working out the **sum of** the Fibonacci numbers, and not the Fibonacci numbers themselves. Accordingly, it might be less contentiously written

```
def sumFibonacci(n):
    if (n<=0):
        return 0
    elif(n==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return sumFibonacci(n-1)+sumFibonacci(n-2)+1
    
n=int(input())
print(sumFibonacci(n))
```

If the Fibonacci numbers are

```
f0, f1, f2, ... = 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...
```

then the sums are

```
S0, S1, S2, ... = 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, ...
```

and fit the given formula.

For a proof set out the successive downward sequence:

[image]

and sum the columns:

[image]

Just like the Fibonacci numbers themselves, however, such a recursive method is not a good one unless you use memoisation (storing what is already calculated), since each call spawns two more and your stack grows exponentially. I suggest that you just use a loop.

Comment: Damn thats an elegant proof with summing the columns. Did you think of that one yourself?

Comment: I did, @juanpethes, but it was more of a pain to type than derive it! Next time I'll upload a scan of my hand scribbles rather than word-processing and snipping it.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(n)` be the *n*th Fibonacci number, and `S(n)` be the sum of the first *n* Fibonacci numbers.

It can be shown ([proof at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Combinatorial_proofs)) that:

`S(n) = f(n+2) - 1` **(1)**

Now, given that, we can substitute `n-1` and `n-2` into equation (1) and find that:

`S(n-1) = f(n+1) - 1`

and

`S(n-2) = f(n) - 1`

Adding those, we get:

`S(n-1) + S(n-2) = f(n+1) + f(n) - 2` **(2)**

By definition of the Fibonacci series:

`f(n+2) = f(n+1) + f(n)`

So substituting that back into (2):

`S(n-1) + S(n-2) = f(n+2) - 2` **(3)**

From (1) and (3), we can now see that:

`S(n) = f(n+2) - 1 = [f(n+2) - 2] + 1`

i.e. `S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n-2) + 1` **(4)**

Equation (4) is what your Python function implements. As has been said in comments, it might be best to rename it to something like `fibonacci_sum` rather than `fibonacci`.

Answer (score 0):

The SUM of the first `n` fibonacci numbers g(n) is obtained by `g(n) = g(n-1)+g(n-2)+1` (that's the formula)

You can verify this by manually adding up the fibonacci numbers with the sum() function.

Here are two simpler versions of the functions to compute fibonacci numbers and their sum (without the exponential recursion):

```
def fibo(n,a=1,b=0):
    return fibo(n-1,a+b,a) if n else a

def fiboSum(n,a=0,b=0,c=0):
    return fiboSum(n-1,a+b+1,a,b) if n else a
```

You can observe that the fiboSum() function produces the same result as adding up the first n fibonacci numbers (0...n inclusively):

```
for n in range(26):
    added = sum(fibo(k) for k in range(n+1))
    print(n, "f(n):",fibo(n), "\t∑f(n):", added, 
             "\tg(n):", fiboSum(n),"\tYours:",fibonacci(n))

0 f(n): 0   ∑f(n): 0    g(n): 0     Yours: 0
1 f(n): 1   ∑f(n): 1    g(n): 1     Yours: 1
2 f(n): 1   ∑f(n): 2    g(n): 2     Yours: 2
3 f(n): 2   ∑f(n): 4    g(n): 4     Yours: 4
4 f(n): 3   ∑f(n): 7    g(n): 7     Yours: 7
5 f(n): 5   ∑f(n): 12   g(n): 12    Yours: 12
6 f(n): 8   ∑f(n): 20   g(n): 20    Yours: 20
7 f(n): 13  ∑f(n): 33   g(n): 33    Yours: 33
8 f(n): 21  ∑f(n): 54   g(n): 54    Yours: 54
9 f(n): 34  ∑f(n): 88   g(n): 88    Yours: 88
10 f(n): 55     ∑f(n): 143  g(n): 143   Yours: 143
11 f(n): 89     ∑f(n): 232  g(n): 232   Yours: 232
12 f(n): 144    ∑f(n): 376  g(n): 376   Yours: 376
13 f(n): 233    ∑f(n): 609  g(n): 609   Yours: 609
14 f(n): 377    ∑f(n): 986  g(n): 986   Yours: 986
15 f(n): 610    ∑f(n): 1596     g(n): 1596  Yours: 1596
16 f(n): 987    ∑f(n): 2583     g(n): 2583  Yours: 2583
17 f(n): 1597   ∑f(n): 4180     g(n): 4180  Yours: 4180
18 f(n): 2584   ∑f(n): 6764     g(n): 6764  Yours: 6764
19 f(n): 4181   ∑f(n): 10945    g(n): 10945     Yours: 10945
20 f(n): 6765   ∑f(n): 17710    g(n): 17710     Yours: 17710
21 f(n): 10946  ∑f(n): 28656    g(n): 28656     Yours: 28656
22 f(n): 17711  ∑f(n): 46367    g(n): 46367     Yours: 46367
23 f(n): 28657  ∑f(n): 75024    g(n): 75024     Yours: 75024
24 f(n): 46368  ∑f(n): 121392   g(n): 121392    Yours: 121392
25 f(n): 75025  ∑f(n): 196417   g(n): 196417    Yours: 196417
```